# Winforms - Performance when using Invoke Sub for update Label in UI

Tags: vb.net, performance, invoke

Regarding an application that i have written that does a alot of file open , search the file and close file in noumerous files of the disk inside one sub, i had the need to inform the user with someway in order to not think that the program is frozen. The best way for me was to keep updating a label with the file name of the file that is currently being proccesed.

I messed with backroundworker and i found it a liitle bit complex and recently i found the simple invoke solution

```
lblStatus.Invoke(Sub()
      lblStatusAll.Text = "Searching .. " & Filename
      Me.Refresh()                          
                End Sub)
```

I exprerience very big difference in the performance when i enable this invoke .
Is there something else i must consider ?

I tried using SuspendLayout() and ResumeLayout(True) but i didnt see any difference.

Comment: You should get rid of that `Refresh` call. That is repainting the entire form every time you set the `Text` of the `Label`. That's the slow part.

Comment: How often is the `Label` being updated? Is what you're doing actually worthwhile at all? Can the user even read the file name? If not then what's the point? Why not just use a `ProgressBar` that shows actual progress if possible or set the `Style` to `Marquee` otherwise.

Comment: Get rid of the Refresh and you might try BeginInvoke instead of Invoke.

Comment: Thanks for the replies . Unfortunatelly non of the above worked, The performance came back although (probably by disabling the Me.Refresh) but the result is that  the label is not visibly refreshed in the ui until all the jobs end and then it shows the last file searched in the label. The idea about having a marquee progress bar just moving around it is not ideally what i would like to do because the user will still have the thought that something may be stuck if it takes time for the job to finish.

Comment: I was wondering if the slow part is the Me.Refresh that reloads the whole form , is there any possibility to decrease the performance impact if a new small popup form was opened while the heavy  job starts and this form was used for the  label updating ? Would this idea make any difference ?